# How is the .= working in this code?

Tags: php

I was given this question as part of learning PHP.

What is the final value of $a?

```
$a .= "a";
$a .= "b";
$a .= "c";
```

I know it outputs "abc" and I understand that ".=" is a concatenation assignment, but I'm still a little unclear what is actually going on here. When I remove the periods I get "c", which makes sense that it would take the last item.

Thanks for any clarity.

Comment: `$a = "a" . "b" . "c";`

Comment: . concatenates. .= allows you to reassign with concatenation. so $a .= "b"; is essentially saying a equals a, but also add "b"

Comment: dot is a [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Read up.

Comment: If you're familiar with Java or C++, this is just like `+=`. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @Chris The difference maybe is that the Java compiler (and I think the C++ too) tell you that there is no string to append to, and PHP doesn't.

Comment: I see - In general I assumed there was more code outside of this snippet.

Comment: @Chris I thought so first too and it's just my guess.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. I'm still new to SO so not sure if I just select the best answer and that's it or if etiquette is to upvote all good answers but select just the best that solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a .= "a"
```

...is shorthand for ...

```
$a = $a . "a"
```

At the beginning, $a is empty.

```
$a .= "a"
// now $a == "a"
$a .= "b"
// now $a == "a" . "b" == "ab"
$a .= "c"
// now $a == "ab" . "c" == "abc"
```

Comment: This was an excellent description. Now I get it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly, it's concat'ing it.  The following two lines are equivalent.

```
$a = $a . "a"   
$a .= "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.=` in PHP you are practically gluing strings together into one.

Test your code by pasting it in here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

then write another line to output the content of the variable `a`

```
$a .= "a";
$a .= "b";
$a .= "c";
echo $a;
```

The final result of the variable `a` is `"abc"` because "a" + "b" + "c" = "abc" - Concatenation!

So in summary, think of the following: The variable `a` is simply a container... When we use the assignment operator (=), we remove whatever its in the container and replace it with the new value we are assigning, this is why when you used `=` the final result was the character `c`. Because it kept on replacing the original content.

When we use concatenation, `.=`we continue to APPEND, instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use $a .= "a" when $a is not defined. in this case you should get "Undefined variable" warning with a correct PHP configuration. Try to fix this problem to get ride of any unexpected value;

Answer (score 0):

```
$a .= "a";   // $a =$a . 'a' ie a= 'a'
$a .= "b"; //  $a =$a . 'b' ie a= 'ab'
$a .= "c"; // $a =$a . 'c' ie a= 'abc'
```